# Close a popover div while clicking outside that div or other parts of the page

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, angularjs-directive

I have created a popover menu as a directive using `angularjs` in my `sharepoint 2013` application. This is been used in all the other pages to show a small help window, while clicking a link. Now, I need to close this menu once the user clicks any where else in the screen other than the close button.

I'm using `SharePoint 2013` and `angularjs`.

How can I achieve this ? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Share the code...please

Answer (score 1):

Use `backdrop` option of angular ui modal. This will help you close the popover bu clicking anywhere in the window other than the popover.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you give me a sample code or link ?

Comment: Thank you very much... Is it possible to achieve this without using ui-bootstrap ? So far, we are not using this in our project.

Comment: I am not sure without ui-bootstrap. You should use the ui-bootstrap.